# PHP script can't read #,".' etc

Tags: php, code-snippets

I have PHP script from here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/ , everything works fine except when I have file or folder with #,",' sign it can't be display in web browsers. So I must rename that file or folder to get it works. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape those characters, with a backslash `\`. I don't know why you would have folders with special characters in the name anyways.

For example if you have a folder named `#Folder` you would need to escape the `#` but doing `\#Folder`.

Comment: Thank for your help, I found a solution by changing urldecode to html_entity_decode

Comment: edited : change urldecode to htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))